# How to get xpub or mpk(bip32) for my bitcoin core wallet?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, bip32-hd-wallets, private-key-export

I m not getting any such option in bitcoin-core Ui and documentation
http://bitcoindaily.org/bitcoin-guides/bitcoin-core-tutorial/

Answer (score 12):

Bitcoin Core (since 0.13) uses HD after BIP32 with only hardened private key derivation. Exporting the xpub would be useless, because other apps could not derive public keys (hardened derivation requires the xpriv).

Though, you can export the xpriv with `dumpwallet <filename>` (RPC or Debug Console). But be careful with that.

Comment: This is an historically accurate answer, even though nowadays dumpwallet might be restricted to only what now are called legacy wallets.