# Does Bitcoin Core support watch-only wallets?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bip32-hd-wallets, watch-only

Is it possible to use Bitcoin Core in a watch-only mode? I want to be able to generate new addresses in an online instance of Bitcoin Core, but keep the private keys separate on another local Bitcoin Core instance.

How would I be able to do that with Bitcoin Core? I don't want to use any third-party solutions, preferably only Bitcoin Core.

Comment: What do you mean with "Not with addresses, but with watch-only wallets."? What would you be watching if not an address?

Comment: @Murch. address. but, now in order to use a watch-only address, I have to generate it somewhere else, say, on my local computer, and then import it on a server by "importaddress". whereas I want to generate it on a server and have it watch-only right away. watch-only wallet has to able to do that.

Comment: Hey, I've had another look at your question and edited to clarify what you want to do. I hope that the resulting post captures your intent, otherwise please feel free to further edit or amend it. Thanks.

Comment: It seems to be impossible: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/50247/77103

Answer (score 1):

It's possible if you use a fixed number of addresses. Take a look at https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/5z35nm/watchonly_wallet_in_bitcoin_core_qt/