# Creating HD wallet using Blockcypher

Tags: private-key, bip32-hd-wallets, public-key, blockcypher

I'm using Blockcypher to [create an HD wallet](https://www.blockcypher.com/dev/bitcoin/#create-wallet-endpoint), which requires me to send `extended_public_key`.

How do I create the extended keys?
While generating a new address using [the API](https://www.blockcypher.com/dev/bitcoin/#generate-asset-address-endpoint) I'm getting something like:

```
{
  "private": "696785dc619c5f493ba72aa1ded581771ac7360fcf49903a0dc96a381d460182",
  "public": "03d6ff03e21b81a7f5c7e678130845a94ba1ca15316bc0d9635c8cc3e51aa26a8a",
  "address": "bc1q446jd78q2nmpxt25puv7h8lwcwsw9dmkgf5sgp",
  "wif": "KzkbwXy4PS8mEAnZZC5LcVnhe64LCWaqUfsc4Fuj1AKak4qgBPcJ"
}
```

How can I use this data to create extended private and public keys?

Should I use a different method to generate the extended keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not use the single key pair data to create an extended public key. The single address you generated with the API is not relevant in this situation.  The HD Wallet Endpoint is a feature where you can provide your own extended public key from an external wallet (not blockcyphers).

Related question/answer on extended public keys: [How to generate a new extended public key (xpub)?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/74246/how-to-generate-a-new-extended-public-key-xpub)