# Fetch my private key

Tags: wallet

I goal is to understand. I do not want to earn money with mining.
(I have a server without GPU)

Here is what i've done:

I have downloaded, maked and installed bitcoin sourcecode from github.

It seems to work because i can interact with bitcoind with bitcoin-cli command.

I know this is not a good practice but i want to "see" my private key.

I have read several documentation and tutorials and they said i need to generate an address first, then call dumpprivkey method.

Like this:

```
$ bitcoin-cli getnewaddress
xxxxxxx

$ bitcoin-cli dumpprivkey xxxxxxx
```

I do not understand but if i repeat twice this operation, i get 2 differents private keys.

So this is not the private key i am looking for... What is those privates keys ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> **Let's suppose I have lost everything except this extended master key. How can I setup a new fresh computer and retrieve all my bitcoins just with this key?**

According to [How to get xpub or mpk(bip32) for my bitcoin core wallet?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/50244/13866)

> you can export the xpriv with dumpwallet

According to https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=3866008.0

> Bitcoin Core does not have a way to directly import [master] private keys.
>   You could derive a bunch of private keys in WIF from the xpriv and import them all at once, but you can't import the xprv directly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Everything is very confuse for me. I will do a test : i will take 2 computers. Whats commands should i type on both computer in order to « transfert » my account from first to second computer

Comment: @Bob5421: That's a different question. See https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Backingup_your_wallet - Copy the wallet.dat file from the old wallet and use it to overwrite the wallet.dat file of a newly installed empty wallet on a different computer.

Answer (score 0):

This is the private key that allows you to spend Bitcoin which is sent to the corresponding address.

If you run both of those commands twice, you will generate a new key pair and a new address each time, which will be different.

Comment: Okay but i have another private key somewhere which is global for my account ?

Comment: yes, each key pair is derived from a master key, see https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.18.0/rpc/wallet/dumpwallet/ it will be at the top of the output file.

Comment: Thanks, i can see an "extended" master key. What is the difference between extended and not extended master key (which i cannot see) Thanks

Comment: It is used for hierarchical deterministic key derivation, see https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki

Comment: I see on dumpwallet command a lot of lines with addr What is it (the account is blank, i have do nothing)

Comment: Let's suppose i have lost everything except this extended master key. How can i setup a new fresh computer and retreive all my bitcoins just with this key

Comment: @Bob5421 did you ever figure this out. I'm trying to do the same thing.  I have a wallet on my phone and want to use that master private key to import into Bitcoin Core. I don't want to create a new wallet on Bitcoin Core and transfer everything from current wallet to BC wallet.