# how to get the private key in Bitcoin Core 26.0.0 and how to create a legacy wallet

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, database

i had tried many methods but nothing help me
[image: Text],
by using `bitcoind -deprecatedrpc=create_bdb`
[image: Text]
i think i had installed the Berkeley DB
please help me to solve the problem

Comment: Do you need to create a wallet using Berkeley DB? Why not install sqlite3 as a dependency, build Bitcoin Core again and use the DB that the non-legacy wallet supports? Assuming you don't have any mainnet funds in a legacy Berkeley DB wallet that is.

Comment: but the legacy wallet can be created by using only the bdb , i need the legacy wallet to find the private key in the regtest

Comment: You are creating a new wallet? Regtest is supported in the non-legacy sqlite3 wallet.

Comment: is there is a way to find the private key for the newly created wallet

Comment: dumpprivkey doesn't work for non-legacy but there is an alternative to using dumpprivkey https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/113834/why-can-i-not-dump-private-keys-from-a-descriptor-wallet

Comment: still i don't get the private key !!

Comment: "You can get the master private keys by using listdescriptors true. This will output all of the descriptors stored in the wallet along with their corresponding private keys." If you aren't sure what the private key is here post a different question

Comment: if i use listdescriptors true i only get pkh,sh,tr,wpkh

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve that you are trying to the get the private key for?